# how to get the class annotation with @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The spring searches components base for the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, reference from [Locating the Main Application Class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class).
When I write my own component, I want to be able to use this path as well, but I don't know how to get it.

for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

public static class SomeComponent {
    //I use this to scan my custom annotation
    private String basePackage;

    public SomeComponent(String basePackage) {
        this.basePackage = basePackage;
    }
}

@Configuration
public static class SomeComponentConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.some-component.base-package:}")
    private String basePackage;

    @Bean
    public SomeComponent someComponent() {
        if (basePackage == null) {
            //TODO how to get the Application.class as default path commonly
            basePackage = Application.class.getPackage().getName();
        }
        return new SomeComponent(basePackage);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: post some code samples that your tried already and mention your project structure as well... that can help us to verify your problem

Comment: @ganesh045 i have add a example

Comment: are you trying to read your own component from your main class without using any external annotation that gave by Spring seems like I felt like that with your code sample if that's the case remove `public for SomeComponent` ...if that's not the case use check my answer..

Answer (score 2):

I think this class does what you want:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationFinder {

  @Autowired private ApplicationContext context;

  public String findBootClass() {
    Map<String, Object> candidates = context.getBeansWithAnnotation(SpringBootApplication.class);
    return candidates.isEmpty() ? null : candidates.values().toArray()[0].getClass().getName();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed feasible. Spring also needs to use this path, I think it must be stored where the path can be obtained directly

Comment: You could be right - but I can also imagine implementations in which this path would only be saved in an instance variable in some Spring support object - so there would be no way to get at it.  I don't know the internals of Spring so that I could answer that...